# How to share MSALSessionCache with 2 web applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have developed 2 web applications.
I have used Azure Active Directory v2.0 for user identity.
These two applications are hosted as separate web apps in Azure.
using Application Gateway, I am redirecting the specific request to web apps.

If User is requesting for any of the web apps, then first it is redirected to azure tenant endpoint for authentication.

After successful login, it will be redirected to the main web app and I have followed this below code in OnAuthorizationCodeReceived method.

TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
            ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ApplicationId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ApplicationKey), userTokenCache, null);

Now When User is navigating from one web app to the other web app. I am using below code to get token from the cache.

TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)).GetMsalCacheInstance();
ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.ApplicationId, Startup.Authority, Startup.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(Startup.ApplicationKey), userTokenCache, null);

var user = cca.Users.FirstOrDefault();

When I am implementing this code and try to get token in the second web app.then it will give me null in the user variable and it throws an error.

What Should I Do?

Note: If some user logged in one web apps, then it does not require to log in another web app. Sessions and cookies are shared between all web apps.

Answer (score 0):

The customization of Token cache serialization to share the SSO state between ADAL.NET 3.x, ADAL.NET 4.x and MSAL.NET is explained part of the following sample: [active-directory-dotnet-v1-to-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-v1-to-v2)

This solution shows how to customize token cache serialization in a .NET desktop application so that it shares the Single Sign On (SSO) state between: ADAL.NET V3.x applications, ADAL.NET V4.x applications, MSAL.NET 2.x applications